# Computes Matrix A.transpose*A in cuda

Tags: cuda, gpu, cublas

there are some problem when I'm computing `A.transpose*A' in cuda.

Suppose A is M*N matrix and stored in column-major, and I try to use this function `cublasSgemm_v2` which is the Matrix-Matrix Multiplication API in cublas

like this :

```
cublasSgemm_v2(handle,CUBLAS_OP_T,CUBLAS_OP_N,N,N,M,&al,A,N,A,M,&beta,A_result,N)
```

Before call this function I test matrix A and it looks good , but it shows that parameter number 8 is illegal, I don't know why.

So I decide to use another API to compute A.tanspose*A `cublas<t>syrk()`. And the result returned stored in lower or upper of the matrix that means the rest of matrix is not referenced, and how to write a kernel to copy the elements to the symmetry part?

The other problem is my program sometimes crashed (may be one third possibility ) in beginning of the code like cudaMalloc or cbulascreate or somewhere else, I just modify some code in the middle of code , and it run many times before, what may be cause this?

Thank you

Comment: Please, provide a minimum sized code that someone else could copy, paste, compile and run to reproduce your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the [cublas gemm documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) carefully.

There is a way to compute `A' * A` direct with the `cublas<T>gemm`, but it's tricky.

```
  cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, N, K, M, &alpha,
    A, M, A, M, &beta, B, N);
```

This is a kind of a little hack - A is your matrix of dimension `A(MxN)` stored in column major order and `K = N`.
Therefor as response you wil get `B = A' * A`.

Comment: It haven't to be `K`. I only used it to show up the parameter use. Of course it can be `N`, too.